# how can I enable django user to download portion of the db? or db entered by him?

Tags: django, database, django-rest-framework

I want to help user to save a copy of data entered by him in the cloud, is this feature available in django? or are there an alternatives?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Start by searching for exporting data in the specific file format you'd like.

Comment: I found some packages to export from admin, or exporting as excel file but should I shape my models in a specific way(separated tables) to separate users data? what about rdb?

Comment: As long as your model has a `created_by` field there's a number of ways to accomplish this. If the user downloads the model to CSV or XLSX through a form you could filter the queryset by the request user. You could set up an API endpoint for users and add all the related model serializers to export as JSON.